# What namespaces are predefined in the C# language?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to figure out which namespaces (not assemblies) are predefined in C#.

**Start Edit**

Define the term *predefined*.

The term *predefined* (or pre-defined) is used over 100 times in the C# language specification. Unfortunately, the specification never gives a formal definition of the term. To me, something is predefined if the language specification defines (i.e. specifies) it and guarantees that it will be present.

**End Edit**

For instance, I've created the following program.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var strings = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string> { 
            "Foo",
            "Bar"
        };
        strings.ForEach((s) =>
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(s);
        });
        System.Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

This is its .csproj file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Program.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>
```

Visual Studio is not involved at all. The above project has only two files. It builds with msbuild on the command line and runs as a console app.

Even though I am not referencing any assemblies, the `System.Console` and `System.Collections.List<T>` classes are available. So, I assume that the `System` and `System.Collections` namespaces are predefined in the C# language.

I've been reading the C# language specification to determine which namespaces are predefined. It does list some predefined types, conversions, and operators. It doesn't list all the predefined namespaces though.

What namespaces are predefined in the C# language?

**Edit**

Xanatos provided [code that I placed into a fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/48G3vD). It demonstrates that the mscorlib contains 56 namespaces.

Comment: Visual studio is linking a lot of dlls when you create a new project, such as to system.dll, system.core.dll, etc., which will have these types.  You can write a C# program that doesn't link to those dlls.  Also note that *namespaces* and *assemblies* are very different; you're confusing those two terms.

Comment: @Servy I'm not using Visual Studio. I only have a .csproj and a single .cs file. I'm building with the msbuild command line.

Comment: You are always going to have a reference to mscorlib which has fundamental types needed for the language, eg string, int, etc.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin I would suggest reading up on C# MSDN NameSpace and how to use / define them..

Comment: @MethodMan How would that help to answer my question?

Comment: I suppose you're thinking about this: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/master/src. But what you should realize is that these are just classes and namespaces like any other -- they're just provided by Microsoft.

Comment: The C# compiler adds a reference to mscorlib [unless you explicitly tell it not to with the nostdlib flag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fa13yay7.aspx). That is where all those namespaces are coming from.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin Well, if you read MethodMan's link it'd help you understand that your question has nothing to do with namespaces; you're really interested in assemblies, and they're two very different things.

Comment: Everything you're using is defined in mscorlib.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I'd never seen that. What I'm thinking about is what the C# language provides in and of itself without needing any other references.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin ... MSCORELIB, What part of that are you not understanding?

Comment: @BenjaminPaul I wasn't understanding that the mscorelib was referenced by default when compiling.

Comment: @Servy Just to clarify, I am interested in namespaces not assemblies.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin Then your question makes no sense, and stems from a lack of understanding of what a namespace is; hence the suggestion for you to read a tutorial on what namespaces actually are.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin You are mixing namespaces and assemblies. The same namespace can be defined in multiple assemblies. There is no predefined namespace. There is one automatic assembly (mscorlib).

Comment: @ShaunLuttin: C# doesn't provide a thing in term of default namespaces. Microsoft created the .NET framework which is contained in - amongst others - the mscorlib assembly. This assembly contains the namespaces you mentioned above. C# is a language specification implemented by Microsoft. Microsoft created MSBuild. MSBuild adds mscorlib to your build process.

Comment: If this is truly a requirement then there are none 'we don't have to reference any other assemblies'. All the things you're thinking 'aren't referenced assemblies' are precisely that, the reference is just included when you create a project and the dll it's referencing is already installed on every Windows computer of a similar version. There's no magic happening.

Comment: @xanatos What I mean here by predefined is the same as what I would mean by a predefined type, conversion, or operator. Would you still say there are no predefined namespaces?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using the `csc.exe` compiler. All of the predefined types in the base class library are located in the file mscorlib.dll, which is referenced by default when compiling.

So, your questions is what is defined in that dll.
One place to start is here:

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib,namespaces

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing namespaces and assemblies. Assemblies are containers of compiled code. .NET has many assemblies built by Microsoft (*mscorlib*, *System*, *System.Core*, *System.Data* ...) that are part of the Common Language Runtime.

Each assembly has some classes/structs inside. Normally these classes are grouped in namespaces. It isn't strictly necessary, but Microsoft, being good, did it. Now, these namespaces have often the same name of assemblies (*System*, *System.Data*) (but note that there is no namespace *System.Core* or *mscorlib*). There is no strict relationship between the naming of assemblies and the namespaces defined inside.

A namespace can be defined in multiple assemblies (*System* for example is present in both *mscorlib*, *System*, *System.Core* ...). An assembly can have classes with multiple namespaces (*mscorlib* has classes of *System*, *System.Collections*, *System.IO*, ...)

When you compile a C# program, the *mscorlib* assembly is automatically referenced as an assembly (and I don't think it is possible to compile without referencing it). There is no default namespace in C# (you have to use the `using` to use them, or use the full name of the classes, like `System.Console`)

I suggest you install [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) and look at the various assemblies to comprehend how they are organized.

On MSDN, if you look at any one class/struct of .NET (for example [System.Int32](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.aspx)) you'll see:

> Namespace:  System
>
> Assembly:  mscorlib (in mscorlib.dll)

(I'll say that the ordering is conceptually wrong, because the Assembly should be first, but it isn't really important)

If you really want a list of namespaces "exported" by mscorlib:

```
Assembly mscorlib = typeof(int).Assembly;

var hs = new SortedSet<string>();

foreach (Type type in mscorlib.ExportedTypes)
{
    hs.Add(type.Namespace);
}

foreach (string ns in hs)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ns); 
}
```

Now... if you want to know which classes/structs are *necessary* based on the C# specifications 5.0...

By looking for `System.` I've found these

```
System.Object, System.ValueType, System.Array, System.Enum, System.Delegate
System.Exception, System.Type, System.Attribute

System.SByte, System.Byte, System.Int16, System.UInt16, System.Int32, System.UInt32, System.Int64, System.UInt64, System.Char, System.Single, System.Double, System.Decimal, System.Boolean, System.Object, System.String 

System.MulticastDelegate (not sure)
System.Void
System.IDisposable 
System.Nullable<T>
System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<D>, 
System.Collections.Generic.IList<T> (implicit cast from System.Array, not sure)
System.Threading.Tasks.Task (for async/await)
System.Threading.Tasks.Task<T> (for async/await)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.INotifyCompletion (for async/await)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ICriticalNotifyCompletion (for async/await)
System.Action (for await, resumption delegate)
System.Collections.IEnumerable (for collection initializer and foreach)
System.Collections.IEnumerable<T> (for foreach)
System.Threading.Monitor (for lock)
System.IntPtr/System.UIntPtr (specific type for volatile fields)

// These attribute are directly recognized by C#
System.AttributeUsageAttribute 
System.Diagnostics.ConditionalAttribute 
System.ObsoleteAttribute 
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerLineNumberAttribute
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerFilePathAttribute
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberNameAttribute 
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CSharp.IndexerNameAttribute

// These exceptions seems to be "important" for C#
System.OverflowException
System.InvalidOperationException 
System.NullReferenceException 
System.OutOfMemoryException 
System.DivideByZeroException 
System.ArrayTypeMismatchException 
System.ArithmeticException 
System.TypeInitializationException
System.IndexOutOfRangeException
System.StackOverflowException
```

Note that on top of this there are classes necessary for the `dynamic` but I haven't found any reference of them in the specifications.

Comment: What I'm wondering is not what the default namespace is. What I'm wondering instead, is which namespaces are available when I don't explicitly reference any assemblies. By available, I mean, which ones can I use with a `using` statement or with the full name of a class?

Comment: @Shaun The list is very long. System, System.Collection, System.Collections.Generic, System.Collections.ObjectModel, System.Diagnostics, System.IO, System.Reflection, ... Use ILSpy to look at the mscorlib and see it for yourself

Comment: Thank you for that code. I created a fiddle out of it. https://dotnetfiddle.net/48G3vD I appreciate that. Question: how would you define the term "predefined?"

Comment: @ShaunLuttin You could ask "which classes are part of .NET (version number)" or what is/are the assemblies of .NET necessary to run the smallest program (`mscorlib`) or what are the most used assemblies of .NET (mscorlib, System, System.Core)

Comment: I'm interested in the term as the C# language specification uses it. So, to specify further, how would you define the term *predefined* as the C# language specification uses it and in contrast with the term *user-defined*? I ask because I haven't been able to find a reliable definition.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin I need context. Show me where you've found it

Comment: It occurs 102 times in version 5.0 of the C# specification. The second occurrence is "C# provides a set of predefined struct types called the simple types." (p. 77) See also: http://www.muddlingthru.ca/predefined-vs-user-defined

Comment: @ShaunLuttin I'll say that the specification is badly written :-) Nowhere in the specification is specified for example that the C# uses the mscorlib (or other assemblies), so for "predefined" they could mean "whatever is present in the .NET libraries that we need to run a C# program" (like the various `System.Object`, `System.String`, `System.Enum`, `System.Array`, ...) OR they could mean the whole .NET (comprehending the ASP.NET libraries, the WPF, the Winforms, ...)

Comment: @ShaunLuttin After reading a little I'll say this: the C# specification guarantees that there are some types that will always be present. *It doesn't guarantee where they are defined*. It only guarantees that they are present. There will always be a `System.Double`, with a `double` alias, there will always be a `System.Object` that will be the base class of all the other types, with an alias `object` and so on. The C# doesn't guarantee that the program will be "autonomous" (so that it doesn't require other dll to run). The `mscorlib` assembly and

Comment: the automatical reference of it by the `csc.exe` is the way the C# compiler "implements" these guarantees. If you want a full list of everything that is surely needed... It could be done... But it would be long